# Как получить местоположение - гео-координаты latitude и longitude?

Tags: python, django

Как можно получить местоположение человека, заходящего на страницу?

Нужны гео-координаты latitude и longitude.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ip2geotools/

Comment: @ZaArs В следующий раз подобные правки буду просто отклонять, не обессудьте.